# Fullscreen Pageflip layout

Tags: jquery, css, page-flipping

I'm a follower of Codrops tutorials by Tympanus.

For a friends website's (http://www.selinacarlos.ch/wordpress/) I would like to implement the script Fullscreen Pageflip I've found [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/11/fullscreen-pageflip-layout/).

Now I'm trying to make it no-fullscreen, with a background image. It's working well, but I don't want the menu is visible on the left and that the container slide over the right side.

I've tried with an overflow hidden, but it crops the entire menu.

How can I achieve the desired effect with css?
I've to add another div to the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want

```
.js .menu-panel {
    position: absolute;
    left: -240px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

then in your slideRight class add visibility: visible;

Comment: It's a very good solution.

I've added visibility: visible to .menu-panel when .slideRight appear like so:
`.slideRight > .menu-panel{
 visibility: visible;
}`
Thank you very much!

Comment: if it fits your question you should accept the answer as correct, so others can learn with it, ok?